# Find and replace with Sed in a text file

Tags: sed, replace, find

{"date":"12:44",    **<-----Need to keep the second colon in this line only**
"temp":"38.6",
"tempTL":"38.6",
"tempTH":"46.9",
"intemp":"66.6",
"dew":"36.8",
"dewpointTL":"36.8",
"dewpointTH":"46.9",

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script to upload files.
# Delete current file
rm /home/pi/allsky/realtimegauges.txt
# Get weather text file from web
wget https://www.melvinweather.com/realtimegauges.txt
# Change permissions of text file
chmod 777 realtimegauges.txt
#Replace { with nothing
sed -i 's/{//g' realtimegauges.txt
#Replacedate with time
sed -i 's/date/time/g' realtimegauges.txt
#replace the " with  nothing
sed -i 's/"//g' realtimegauges.txt
# replace the : with = sign.
sed -i 's/:/=/g' realtimegauges.txt
#Remove the trailing ,
sed -i 's/,//g' realtimegauges.txt
# Copy file to the allsky/tmp/extra/
cp realtimegauges.txt /home/pi/allsky/tmp/extra
```

I end up with time=xx=xx
I need to end up with time=00:00

Comment: Other than changing date to time, how does this differ from your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75715997/transform-a-comma-deliniated-file/75733532#75733532)?

Comment: I figured all that out.   now I need to figure out how to keep the second colon in the first line only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you have:

```
sed -i 's/:/=/g' realtimegauges.txt
```

The option `g` means that it will replace **all** matches in each line. If instead you only need it to replace a specific one, in this case only the first match, you can do so:

```
sed -i 's/:/=/1' realtimegauges.txt
```

Which will replace only the **first** match in each line.

Comment: sed -i 's/:/=/1' realtimegauges.txt    So the 1 tells it to replace only the first : in each line?

Comment: Yes, only first match in each line

Comment: @ M.Becerra   Thank you.  I learned something.